# I am unable to copy sample data to populate a table Coginity pro from Redshift

Tags: sql, copy, delimiter, credentials, workbench

I have been trying to copy data to a table in my Coginity Pro but I get the error message below .

I have copied my ARN from redshift and pasted it in the relevant path but I still could not populate the sample data to the tables already created in coginity Pro
below is the error message

Status: ERROR

---

copy users from 's3://awssampledbuswest2/tickit/allusers_pipe.txt'
credentials 'aws_iam_role='
delimiter '|' region 'us-west-2'

---

36ms 2022-11-28T02:23:51.059Z

---

(SQLSTATE: 08006, SQLCODE: 0): An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

@udemeribe . Please check STL_LOAD_ERRORS ( order by date_field(starttime)) table